# Using LG V10 or Motorola in Japan

Tags: japan, cellphones

Traveling to Japan early May for a couple of weeks, exploring options for data access while there for easier navigation, translation, etc.

I have an LG V10 on the Verizon network, my girlfriend has a Motorola Droid Turbo also on Verizon. We got both phones with our plans, so I don't know lock/unlock status.

Can we pop a pre-paid SIM card from a place such as this one (http://japan-wireless.com/) into our phones or are they locked off?

Other issues/concerns/suggestions?

We could rent the portable LTE Wifi Pod, but complicates things by having to mail it back.

Comment: They are very probably locked, ask your carrier about getting them unlocked. If you can't, you can get a pocket wifi.

Comment: Verizon hasn't locked its phones for many years. But the complication here isn't SIM locking, it's radio bands.

Answer (score 1):

You can pop a SIM card into your phones. The [Verizon LG V10](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_v10-7606.php) and the [Verizon Droid Turbo](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_droid_turbo-6727.php) have at least one [LTE radio band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LTE_networks_in_Asia) necessary to talk to at least one Japanese carrier (Band 3; NTT DoCoMo and MVNO operators using their network) in what appear to be [limited areas](http://www.mvno-navi.com/knowledge/summary-docomo-mvno-band.html), so don't count on it working everywhere. [3G doesn't appear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UMTS_networks#Asia) to be a problem, though.

Comment: It seems that LTE Band 3, which both phones support, can be used with Docomo-based prepaid SIMs in Japan. [eConnect](https://www.econnectjapan.com/compatibility) says it is supported in "some areas", but they are all technically the same.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The phones do have LTE band 3. I somehow missed that, as I didn't see that any carriers in Japan offered it. I wouldn't have expected it either; Band 3 is the primary LTE band in Europe.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.mvno-navi.com/knowledge/summary-docomo-mvno-band.html) Band 3 seems mostly limited to major metropolitan areas (Tokyo, Nagoya, Osaka), but the page is almost two years old.